# Unit test fails because of Sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, moq

I use MVC3 and want to test the following action via `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` and `Moq`:

```
public ActionResult index()
{
        Session.Add("username", "Simon");
        var lName = Session["username"] as String;
        var lSessionID = Session.SessionID;
        return Content(lSessionID);
}
```

My unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IndexTest()
{

    // Arrange

    var contextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    mockHttpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);

    StartController controller = new StartController();

    var lResult = controller.index() as ContentResult;

    Assert......;
}
```

My unit-test results in a NullReferenceException:

[image]

I have also tried `MvcContrib.TestHelper` which fails by `Session.SessionID` with message "not implemented yet".

How can I test my Action with unit tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mock setup is incomplete.

You need to setup the `ControllerContextc.HttpContext` to return your `mockHttpContext` and you also need to use your `contextMock` in your `StartController` with setting its `ControllerContext`  property:

So the following setup should work:

```
var contextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();

mockHttpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);   
contextMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.HttpContext).Returns(mockHttpContext.Object);

StartController controller = new StartController();
controller.ControllerContext = contextMock.Object;
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast advice. You have freed me from my pain.